# right justify/align buttons/nav/links in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, right-justified

I can't believe I'm having so much trouble finding the answer to this seemingly simple question.

I have two links in my header. I want them stacked vertically, on the right side of the header.

I have tried using buttons, simple html header/p elements, etc.

I have gone through all the examples I found on getbootstrap.com as well.

I've used pull-right too.

While I can get my links to show on the right side, they are not aligned vertically or appear staggered. Below is one example of What I have tried...

```
<header class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <?php include 'db-atch.php';?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
        <h4 class="pull-right"><a href="support">support</a></h4>
        <h4 class="pull-right push-down"><a href="login.php">admin</a></h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: two minutes after asking, I figured it out. Should I delete this question?      The Solution-->  <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#">support</a></button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">login.php">admin</a></button>
    </div>

Comment: if you think it can be useful for anyone add the answer yourself

Comment: I can't seem to get the code to show correctly... :/

Comment: You need to add it as an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done on behalf of you.

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <a href="#">support</a>
 </button> 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">login.php">admin</a>
</button> 
</div>
```